# How do I use $form_state to return data from the from submission handler to the form builder?

Tags: forms

I am trying to populate a data based on `$form_state` right after submission.
What I am trying to do is to populate a form that takes a keyword and passes it to a function that gets the result from another site.

I can use `$form_state['values']['keyword']` in `MYMODULE_form_submit()` but not in `MYMODULE_form_page()`.

How can I achieve this?

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  // Module settings.
  $items['MYMODULE'] = array(
    'title' => 'MYMODULE',
    'description' => 'MYMODULE',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_form_page',
    'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_submit){
  $form['kname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('What would you like to search:'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Please insert the keyword you whish to search for.'),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Send',
  );

  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $keyword = $form_state['values']['kname'];
  $op = MYMODULE_simple_page($keyword);

  return $op;
}

function MYMODULE_form_page($op) {
  $build = array(
    'header_text' => array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<p></p>',
    ),
    'example_form2' => drupal_get_form('MYMODULE_form'),
    array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => '<p>'. $op .'</p>',
    ),
  );

  return $build;
}

function MYMODULE_simple_page($keyword) {
  // Query the external website.
  $data = drupal_http_request('API_ADRESS_JSON');

  // Decode JSON.
  $test = drupal_json_decode($data->data);
  $outitem = '';
  $output = '';
  // Loop through the array (converted from JSON) and view the list of the result as titles and images.
  if (isset($test)) {
    for ($i=0; $i<count($test['images']); $i++) {
      $imageName = $test['images'][$i]['title'];
      $variables = array(
        'path' => $test['images'][$i]['thumbnail_path'], 
        'alt' => 'Test alt',
        'title' => 'Test title',
        'attributes' => array('class' => 'some-img', 'id' => 'my-img'),
      );
      $img = theme('image', $variables);
      $outitem .= '<div class=image><p><strong>'. $imageName .'</strong></p> <br><p>'. $img .'</p> <br></div>';
    }
  }

  $output .= $outitem;

  return $output;
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. Nothing really forces you to save data anywhere. You can unset it, never save it to the database, whatever you please. If you need short time storage, one to keep data between pages for example, there is [Cache API](http://drupal.org/node/145279) just for that. So what's your actual problem? Seems I fail to understand your question, sorry.

Comment: The OP wants to return to the form build the result of the search doing the keyword the users provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only functions that get `$form_state` are form builders, form validation handlers, and form submission handlers.

To say the truth, your code doesn't need to use `MYMODULE_form_page()`: You can simply use the form builder function.

```
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  // Module settings.
  $items['MYMODULE'] = array(
    'title' => 'MYMODULE',
    'description' => 'MYMODULE',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('MYMODULE_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
  return $items;
}

function MYMODULE_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['header_text' => array(
    '#markup' => '<p></p>',
  );

  $form['kname'] = array(
    '#title' => t('What would you like to search'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description' => t('Please insert the keyword you whish to search for.'),
  );

  if (isset($form_state['MYMODULE_result'])) {
    $form['footer_text'] = array(
      '#markup' => '<p>'. $form_state['MYMODULE_result'] .'</p>',
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Send',
  );

  return $form;
}

function MYMODULE_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $keyword = $form_state['values']['kname'];
  $op = MYMODULE_simple_page($keyword);

  // Form submission handlers don't return any value.
  // If you need to return a value to the form builder, you should use the following code.
  $form_state['MYMODULE_result'] = $op;
  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
}
```